# Java package for eigenvector/eigenvalues computation?

Tags: java, package, eigenvalue, eigenvector

which java package do you recommend for computing eigenvectors/eigenvalues? I know about [JMathTools](http://jmathtools.berlios.de/doku.php) and [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/); do you have some pro/cons for these packages? Other suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a more centralized place on numerical computing in Java take a look at this website http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/#libraries , that covers well known libraries presenting them in a convenient manner.

What has been suggested so far is covered on that site, plus many other packages.

Take the time and decide upon one that suits your needs. Enjoy.

Comment: "Due to a lapse in government funding, the National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) is closed and most NIST and affiliated web sites are unavailable until further notice. We sincerely regret the inconvenience." -- is this an impact of government shutdown? :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried taking a look at [JScience](http://jscience.org/experimental/javadoc/org/jscience/mathematics/algebraic/matrices/LinearMathUtils.html) ? I've not used it, but the folks behind JScience seems quite competent.

There is also [UJMP](http://www.ujmp.org/), that I've also never tested.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look at [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/index.html).